# When to use laravel filled() Vs PHP empty()

Tags: laravel

The filled function Vs using the empty function. What is the reason for choosing filled Vs !empty()?

Comment: for `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, check emptiness with `$c = new Collection(); $c->isEmpty(); $c->push('item'); $c->isEmpty();` [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-isempty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big difference between [filled](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-filled) or its inverse [blank](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-blank) and [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is what is considered empty.

For example:

```
filled(0);    // true
blank(0);     // false
!empty(0);    // false

filled('  '); // false;
blank('  ');  // true;
!empty('  '); // true;

filled('');   // false;
blank('');    // true;
!empty('');   // false;
```

The functions work in a very different way, so it's not a matter of just picking one of the two. It depends on what you are trying to do in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think they basically do the same work. The only difference that I noticed is that the `filled()` method is a Laravel's helper function and only available on a `$request` instance or in the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class. While the `empty()` method is available globally because its a PHP's helper function. You can use `empty()` on any variable in any class or controller. While on the other hand `filled()` can only be used wherever you're receiving a request or you have to manually create an instance of `Request` class.

*Personally, I've never used the `filled()` method, so I can't tell you exactly what is the technical difference between them (if there is any).*

Comment: This answer is wrong. The function is part of a helper class, so it's available anywhere. They also do not work in the same way at all. See my answer for examples.

Comment: @BramVerstraten Thanks for the correction. Like I said I've never used the `filled()` method. I thought it only belongs to the request class as its stated in their [API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_filled). I understood now what it does.

Answer (score 0):

**empty example**

```
$test = array(
1 => '',
2 => "",
3 => null,
4 => array(),
5 => FALSE,
6 => NULL,
7=>'0',
8=>0,
);

foreach ($test as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($v)) {
        echo "<br> $k=>$v is empty";
    }
}
/**
Output
1=> is empty
2=> is empty
3=> is empty
4=>Array is empty
5=> is empty
6=> is empty
7=>0 is empty
8=>0 is empty
**/


if(isset($test)) // return true because $test is defined
if(is_null($test)) // return false because $test is not null
```